# The length of a char array

Tags: c, memory, stack

Can anyone explain why strlen returned 1 knowing that ptr1's size is 4 ?

```
int main()
{
    char ptr1[4];
    printf("%lu", strlen(ptr1));
}
```

Result is : 1

Comment: What were you expecting it to return?

Comment: When you have a train with 2 people (but capacity for 100) what's it's length (in terms of people)? Your array (the train) has capacity for 4 chars; but the 2nd char is `'\0'`, so `strlen()` ignores it and all following chars..

Comment: so what is the first character in ptr1 ? is it just a garbage value ?

Comment: yep, **complete garbage**... only thing we know is that it's not a `'\0'`. ... BTW **all other characters (including the `'\0'`) are garbage**.

Comment: Since you didn't initialize the array to any particular value and `strlen` scans for the first 0, it found one at the second byte. `It could have just as easily said 42 or kept going until it poked some memory that crashed your program.

Comment: `strlen()` returns the length of a string, it doesn't return the size of an array.

Comment: @IsmailBarrous I can explain. It occurred such a way that the first character of the uninitialized array is not zero but the second character is zero.

Comment: If you want the size of the array, then you should write `sizeof ptr1` instead of `strlen(ptr1)`.

Comment: does it always add '\0' to the second slot regardless of the array's size ?

Comment: @IsmailBarrous: Since you did not initialize the content of the array to any value, the values of its elements are unspecified, which means that they can be anything. It is probably whatever value was left over from running other code. This also applies to the second element which you are asking about.

Comment: All right thank you guys for the help ! I appreciate it <3

Comment: Side note: The function `strlen` returns an integer of type `size_t`. The correct conversion format specifier for `size_t` is `%zu`, not `%lu`. See the documentation for [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) for further information. Even if using `%lu` for `size_t` happens to work on your [platform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computing_platform), it may fail on other platforms. A good compiler should habe warned you about this error, if you have all warnings enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The size of an array is only available within the same lexical context using the `sizeof` operator.

Example:

```
int main()
{
    char ptr1[4];
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(ptr1));
}
```

This also works for variable length arrays, but not for array parameters to functions, as those are really pointers, so be careful.

`strlen` on the other hand computes the length of a C string by searching for the terminating NUL byte, not really useful for non-string arrays.  Also, because the array has an unspecified value, calling `strlen` on it will cause undefined behavior if none of the values in the array happen to be NUL; and even when you intend to use it with text strings you need to make extra sure the string is NUL-terminated, or alternatively, use `strnlen` (POSIX) or `memchr` (C89).

Comment: Since the array content is undefinded, UB is guaranteed.

Comment: Maybe the wording should be "unspecified" instead.

Comment: Fine by me :), go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

`strlen()` returns number of characters till reaching to `\0` (exluding `\0`).

and also, the initial value of char[] is not deterministic and we cant be sure about it.

in your case, your array has the capacity of four but it might be initialize with something like {'a','\0', ... } so `strlen()` returned 1.

you can use

```
size_t n = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
```

to get number of element in array (which is 4 in your case).

Comment: Going over the length of the array is UB: `char t[2] = {'h', 'i'}; int len = strlen(t); // UB, beware!!`

Comment: specifically, I meant in this case, but as far as I know, it's not guaranteed. thanks for remaining @AndreasWenzel

Comment: yes yes, you're right. that was my mistake. thanks for telling@AndreasWenzel